# How to get the image start and end point, so will add button on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

we are adding the button on image, but the image loaded as aspect ratio not 100% width of div container. Used the background size property to load image as aspect ratio in container. Added go button image but the button left and top based on div container so it is not looking good.

We are using angular directive to set the background image.

```
.go-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.6rem;
  margin-left: -3rem;
 }

.project {
 flex-grow: 1;
 max-width: 30rem;
 background-size: auto 16.9rem;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
 background-position: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
}
```

But client want dynamic button top and height according to the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYZYT.png)

Comment: DONE!. In my case we handled using the directive get image is vertical or horizontal using image object and passed the src. If the image size is vertical then used one css class otherwise for horizontal created new css class and applied. The css class nothing but the top & left according to the image size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the parent of the image to relative, and the button to absolute. Like below:

```
<div class="image-wrapper>
    <img src="url.jpg" />
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

and the button should be absolute with relative to image-wrapper

```
.image-wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```